# Can't pass js value "pageUid" in f:link.page viewhelper

Tags: javascript, typo3, extbase

I get some values from js and formatting page. I used fluid viewhelper for create link. My js look like

```
function buildEstablishments(title, page) {
...
 $('#myid').append(
  '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">' +
  '<f:link.page pageUid="' + page + '" title="' + title + '" >More</f:link.page>' +
'</div>'
  );
}
```

Everything works good, but I can't pass value "pageUid" in f:link.page viewhelper. Parametr ' + page + ' is exists and has a value. How can even pass values? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can not, in simple words all Fluid syntax works on **server side** and JS works on **client side**, that means that server side job is done long, long before it goes to the client (if you're using caching it may be months or years before client side will load it), you can use it rather like this:

**In your Fluid view**:

```
<div onclick="buildEstablishments('{someTitle}', '{f:uri.page(pageUid: somePageUid)}')">Foo Bar Baz</div>
```

Where of course `{someTitle}` and `{somePageUid}` are resolvable Fluid variables

so you can use it in your **JS script** like:

```
function buildEstablishments(title, href) {
    // ...
    $('#myid').append(
        '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">' +
        '<a href="' + href + '" title="' + title + '" >More</a>' +
        '</div>'
    );
}
```